# left join with count

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count, left-join

I am trying to create a query that can count the number of females taking a particular module but am having trouble with getting the create statement.

I have a module table with:

```
module_code
module_title
module_level
```

and my student table has:

```
student_no
student_init
student_lname
student_gender 
.. and so on
```

This is what I have right now. I don't think I am heading the right direction:

```
 SELECT COUNT (*) “Total” 
FROM MODULE 
LEFT OUTER JOIN STUDENT
ON MODULE.MODULE_TITLE
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT (*) “Total” FROM MODULE 
WHERE MODULE_TITLE = COMPUTER SECURITY
LEFT JOIN STUDENT
```

Comment: Have you tried your queries?

Comment: well i know it is not fuly complete as i would need to select student_gender from student before to count it i just don't know how to do that

Comment: You must have a module enrollment table, too, correct?  You need to throw that one into your query.  And you should use an INNER join rather than OUTER.

Comment: yeah i have module enrollment table which has: me_module_code, semester_year and semister_no

Comment: @joshwaa - You'll need the student_id in there, too.

Comment: is there not a way of just going from module table to student?

Comment: No - you need a record somewhere that says Student X is enrolled in Module Y.  How else will you know who has enrolled for each module?  I'll propose an answer with table structure.

Comment: ah okay, sorry i am fairly new at this kind of stuff so say if i did add student_id to the module enrollment what would be the code for the query

Comment: @bassrek why not use outer join? it's likely a valid requirement to show modules with no female enrollments.

Comment: Good point @Sentinel

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you add a `student_id` column to your `module_enrollments` table, you can get the count like so:

```
SELECT     m.module_title
           , COUNT(*)
FROM       module_enrollments me
INNER JOIN student s ON s.ID = me.student_id
INNER JOIN module  m ON m.ID = me.module_id
WHERE      s.Gender = 'F'
GROUP BY   m.module_title
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to show modules that have no women enrolled in addition to counts for those modules where women are enrolled.  For that you do need to use an outer join:

```
 SELECT m.module_title
      , COUNT( s.student_id ) female_cnt
   FROM student s
   JOIN module_enrollment me
     ON s.student_id = me.student_id
    AND s.gender       = 'F'
  RIGHT JOIN module m
     ON me.module_id = m.module_id
  GROUP BY m.module_title;
```

Additionally since you don't want to accidentally filter out modules with no female enrollments, the `s.gender = 'F'` predicate should be part of the join criteria between `students` and `module_enrollment` instead of as part of the `where` clause.

Alternatively you can use a pivot:

```
with src as (
 SELECT m.module_title
      , s.gender
   FROM student s
   JOIN module_enrollment me
     ON s.student_id = me.student_id
  RIGHT JOIN module m
     ON me.module_id = m.module_id
)
 select *
   from src PIVOT (count(*) cnt
              for gender in ('F' as female));
```

If you really want to use a `LEFT` join instead of `RIGHT` join you can still do that:

```
select m.module_title
     , count(s.student_id)
  from module m
  left join module_enrollment me
       join student s
         on s.student_id = me.student_id
        and s.gender = 'F'
    on me.module_id = m.module_id
 group by module_title;
```

It's just not as easy to read.